# Difference between system and shell_exec

Tags: php, shell

What is the difference between `shell_exec` and `system` methods in PHP?

Both take a single command line argument and runs that within PHP. Is it better to use one over the other?

Comment: Can't you just read the docs for [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) and [`system`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With system is possible to capture the return code. Already with the shell_exec is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

See the explanation here:

http://chipmunkninja.com/Program-Execution-in-PHP%3A-exec-m@

Answer (score 2):

I think the main different is when PHP is running in safe mode. System will still work with some restriction as described in documentation however shell_exec will be disabled.